# Application of law of iterated expectations

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I would like your help to show a statement that uses the law of iterated expectations.

In my notation $Supp_X$ denotes the support of a random variable $X$.

Consider the random variables $\epsilon, X, Y$. Take the function $z: Supp_X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^L$ with $L>1$. Take the function $r: Supp_{(X,Y)}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$.

Assume that $E(\epsilon| X,Y)=0$. I want to show that 
$$
E(\epsilon \times r(X,Y) \times  z_l(X))=0 \hspace{1cm} \forall l=1,...,L
$$
where $z_l(X)$ is the $l$-th element of $z(X)$.

I believe that this statement makes uses of the law of iterated expectations but I'm not sure how to show it formally. I'm confused because I've always used the law of iterated expectations to get rid of the conditioning event, which is not the case here

Comment: Thanks: could you suggest which independence assumptions would help me to show what I want? Why $E(\epsilon|X,Y)$ is not sufficient?

Comment: Are you referring to $X$ independent of $Y$?

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb E[\epsilon|X,Y]=0$ is sufficient.

Comment: Is this the proof? Let $x,y,e$ denote realisations of $X,Y,\epsilon$, respectively. $E(\epsilon|X,Y)=0$ $\rightarrow$ $\sum_{x,y} \Big(\sum_e e*\frac{P(e,x,y)}{P(x,y)} \Big)* r(x,y)* z_l(x)* P(x,y)=0$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\sum_{x,y} \Big(\sum_e e*P(e,x,y) \Big) * r(x,y)* z_l(x) \frac{P(x,y)}{{P(x,y)}}=0$  $\leftrightarrow$ $E(\epsilon*r(X,Y) * z_l(X))=0$

Comment: Without the independence assumption, the result is not generally true.  For instance, suppose $\epsilon = r.$  With the independence assumption, the expectation factors with one factor being $E[\epsilon]=0$ and you're done.